# Symfony3 Using Bootstrap Set Form Label/Widget Widths

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony-forms, symfony

I'm using the new built-in bootstrap styles in a Symfony3 appliaction.

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
            - bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig
```

I am using this to render a form by it's components (label and widget).
All the labels have a class for width of col-xs-2 and the widgets class for width is col-xs-10.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.name) }}
    <div class="col-md-9">
       {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
         {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I set (either globally on all forms, or on a form_row, or on each component, eg form_label/form_widget) the class to use. I have tried adding the class, but this just adds to the existing class not replacing it.

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'gfdg', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-3'} }) }}
```

Which renders `class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"`

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but this might help someone in the future.

If you want to set it **globally**, simply create a twig file for example `form/bootstrapCols.html.twig`, and add this two blocks:

```
{% block form_label_class -%}
col-sm-2
{%- endblock form_label_class %}

{% block form_group_class -%}
col-sm-10
{%- endblock form_group_class %}
```

That way you will override those blocks inside [bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig). Change `col-sm-2` and `col-sm-10` to whatever you need and update config file with additional form theme like this:

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig','form/bootstrapCols.html.twig']
```

If you want to change `col-` **for just one view**, then simply in your twig view file use this:

```
{% form_theme formname with ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig', _self] %}
```

and add blocks `form_label_class` and `form_group_class` in the same file with classes you need.

Comment: Thank you for this information. It is still valid and compatible with Symfony 5 and bootstrap5 form if anyone needs it. I wanted a simple solution to overide existing form-group class as it is fixed to col-sm-10 without need of writing entire new theme or writing lots of html stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should customize the look of your form elements, like explained here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html